# Enable Pantheon notifications?

Tags: notifications, vlc

How do I enable Pantheon notifications (e.g. for a certain application)? By accident I removed the ability for notifications while using VLC (with dconf editor), and would like to know if I'm able to rectify the mistake.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Enable notifications for VLC:

1. Open menu **Tools** > **Preferences**.

   [image: Screenshot of step 1]
2. Now, under **Show settings**, select the **All** radio button. Then, from the left sidebar, choose **Control interfaces**. There, check the **LibNotify Notification Plugin** checkbox, then click the **Save** button.

   [image: Screenshot of step 2]
3. By default the notification appears for 4000 ms, i.e. 4 seconds. You can change this duration in the same preferences window, by selecting the **Control interfaces** > **Notify** option in the left sidebar.

Comment: Now you will see vlc option in system notification, there you can manage eneble/disable :) @hm27